# Get Parent Id for a child in a Parent Child table?

Tags: sql

I have an excel table that contains the ID, NodeType, ParentName and Depth of each node.

I wanted to get the corresponding parent ID for all the NodeType using the depth in SQL.

Could anyone please help ?

Sample Table :

```
Id  Node    Parent  Depth
1   a       NULL    0
2   b       a       1
3   c       a       1
4   d       b       2 
5   e       b       2
6   f       c       2
7   g       c       2
```

Expected Result : Get Parent Id for each Node.

```
Id  Node    Parent  Depth  Parent Id
1   a       NULL    0 
2   b       a       1
3   c       a       1
4   d       b       2 
5   e       b       2
6   f       c       2
7   g       c       2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [CTE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms175972(v=sql.120).aspx) to resolve your issue:

Prepare the environment:

```
create table AnyTable (
    Id int identity(1,1) not null
    , [Node] varchar(max) not null 
    , [Parent] varchar(max) null 
    , [Depth] int not null 
)

insert AnyTable 
select 'a', null, 0
union 
select 'b', 'a', 1
union 
select 'c', 'a', 1
union 
select 'd', 'b', 2
union 
select 'e', 'b', 2
union 
select 'f', 'c', 2
union 
select 'g', 'c', 2
```

The CTE query example:

```
;with cteRecursive as (
    select Id, [Node], [Parent], [Depth], null [ParentId]
    from 
        AnyTable
    where 
        [Parent] is null
    union all
    select a.Id, a.[Node], a.[Parent], a.[Depth], c.[Id] [ParentId]
    from 
        AnyTable a 
        join cteRecursive c 
            on a.[Parent] = c.[Node]
)
select 
    * 
from 
    cteRecursive
```

Comment: Could you please explain the cte query a bit ?

Comment: CTE is Common table expressions basicly you would use when you need create a different scope for a specific query like a temporary table but its a large topic to explain, you can see more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql)

Comment: Thank you so much Leo for all your help :)